# How to define Systick handler function Code Composer Studio for cc1310?

Tags: arm, embedded, texas-instruments, code-composer

I opened a new NoRTOS CCS project and modified as follows for using periodic systick interrupt:

1. STCSR Register -> bit0 defined as 0  // Systick disabled
2. STRVR Register -> RELOAD value defined  // 24MHz clock every step is 41.6ns
3. NVIC_IPR3 Register -> bit24 priority is defined for Systick
4. STCSR Register -> bit0, bit1, bit2 are set //Systick enabled

with this modification when the Current value of Systick is 0, COUNTFLAG(16th bit of STCSR Register) gets set as should be.

My problem is defining Systick handler.
There is no startup.s file in the project folder. So I can not find the vector table.

Where is the vector table is defined in CCS projects?

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Best Kind Regards,

Comment: they use weak linking. Just name it SysTickIntHandler and you are set

Comment: Hey Maxim, I really thank you for your help.
But "SysTickIntHandler" also did not work.
SysTickIntHandler is not defined in entire project neighter.

in CCS projects there is no vector table. So I don't know how can I call the handler function.